# FTP Layer - How to do Logging?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, logs

I have a custom extension where I need to write information to a log file.
For this I am using this code:

```
jimport('joomla.log.log'); // Include the log library
$priorities = JLog::ALL ^ JLog::WARNING; // exclude warning (because of deprecated)
$logFileName = 'myextension.log.php';
$logCategory = 'com_myextension';
try {
    JLog::addLogger(array('text_file' => $logFileName), $priorities, $logCategory);
    JLog::add($msg, JLog::INFO, $logCategory);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // logging failed because of unknown reasons, no further action / attempts
}
```

This works excellent on all Joomla installs 2.x to 3.x - except for the ones which have the FTP Layer enabled.

I have read [on the Joomla Dev CMS list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-cms/MMMTpCXadAc/ZKXI8DRyLnAJ) that JLog does not support the FTP layer.

How can I deal with it?
Or more specifically: how can I write my own version of `JLogLoggerFormattedtext` that uses FTP when that layer is enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can override the JLogLoggerFormattedtext class with your own version in one of two ways:

**System Plugin**

Via a System plugin that triggers onAfterInitialise():

```
/**
* Registers core library overrides.
*
* @return   void
*/
public function onAfterInitialise()
{
    // Override /libraries/joomla/log/logger/formattedtext.php 
    JLoader::register('JLogLoggerFormattedtext', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/custom/core-overrides/joomla/log/logger/formattedtext.php');
}
```

However, by the time onAfterInitialise() is called many core classes have already been initialized and so this method wont work. I don't know if JLogLoggerFormattedtext falls into this category or not.

**Core Hack**

First, obviously, core hacks are evil. But I've yet to find a working solution when the plugin method doesn't work.

Modify /ROOT/index.php and/or /ROOT/administrator/index.php (depending on if you need this modification for back-end or front-end executions. Put this code:

```
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/custom/core-overrides/coreOverrideAutoloader.php';
spl_autoload_register('CoreOverrideAutoloader::loader', true, true);
```

directly before:

```
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
```

(both index.php files have that line)

Create /custom/core-overrides/coreOverrideAutoloader.php:

```
<?php
class CoreOverrideAutoloader
{

    public static $requested = array();
    public static $filesLoaded = array();
    public static $filesNotLoaded = array();

    public static function loader($class)
    {
        CoreOverrideAutoloader::$requested[] = $class;

        $filename = __DIR__ . '/' . strtolower($class) . '.php';
        $file=$filename;

        if (!file_exists($file))
        {
            CoreOverrideAutoloader::$filesNotLoaded[] = $file;
            return false;
        }
        include $file;
        CoreOverrideAutoloader::$filesLoaded[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Then create /custom/core-overrides/jlogloggerformattedtext.php

That'll hold your modified JLogLoggerFormattedtext class:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

class JLogLoggerFormattedtext extends JLogLogger
{
    ...
}
```

Creating any other library overrides is as simple as creating additional jclassname.php files in that same folder.